Lower bound on the following quotient of cosinus
For a fixed value of $n, k \in\{1,2,3,\dots,n-1\}$ and $r \in \{1,2,\dots,n/2-1\}$
can we derive a lower bound (in terms of $r$) on the function
$$\frac{\cos(\frac{2\pi k(r+1)}{n})-\cos(\frac{2\pi \cdot(-rk)}{n})}{\cos(\frac{2\pi k}{n})-1})$$
I ran it for $n <500$ (and all valid values for $k$ and $r$), the lowest value I got so far was $-80.42$ for $n=499,r = 187, k=497$ - so this does not seem to be bounded by a constant. Further, in all instances, I observed
$$\frac{\cos(\frac{2\pi k(r+1)}{n})-\cos(\frac{2\pi \cdot(-rk)}{n})}{\cos(\frac{2\pi k}{n})-1} > -r/2$$
Do you have any idea about proving such a lower bound of -r/2?

Please check the expression. You describe $k$ but the expression has $j$. Also, it's curious that $j(r+1)$ is multiplied by $2\pi$ in one cosine, and $rj$ is subtracted from $2\pi$ in another. Also-also, there's an extra "$)$".

BTW, using the sum-to-product and half-angle identities, one can reduce an generalized version of your expression thusly:
$$\frac{\cos a - \cos b}{\cos c - 1} =
\frac{\sin\frac12(a-b)\sin\frac12(a+b)}{\sin^2\frac12c}$$

@Blue sorry for the typos - the Expression should be correct now.

Note that $\cos(x)=\cos(-x)$. We can simplify the expression as follows:
$$\frac{\cos\left(\frac{2\pi k}{n}(r+1)\right)-\cos\left(\frac{2\pi k}{n}r\right)}{\cos\left(\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right)-1}=\frac{2\sin\left(\frac{\pi k}{n}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi k}{n}(2r+1)\right)}{2\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi k}{n}\right)}=\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi k}{n}(2r+1)\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi k}{n}\right)},$$
which is the Dirichlet Kernel $D_{r}\left(\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right)$. Hence, it's equiavlent to
$$1+2\sum_{m=1}^r\cos\left(\frac{2\pi k}{n}m\right).$$
A trivial bound for this expression would be from $1-2r$ to $1+2r$, but perhaps messing around with it a bit more could lead to tighter results.
We can also conclude that your $-\frac{r}{2}$ bound does not hold. For instance, if we have $n=100$, setting something like $r=1$ and $k=51$ makes expression close to $-1$, which is less than $-\frac r2=-\frac 12$.

thanks a lot for the reference to the Dirichlet Kernel. Now, I am quite out of my comfort zone (as my original area is graph theory), but the following reference claims a result of the minimum value of the Dirichlet kernel: http://www.idmercer.com/dirichletkernel.pdf  Their lower bound would yield roughly -0.45r (somehow this again does not fit your example, so maybe there is some -1 missing)

@MrLemming If you look at the Proposition of page 5 of the paper, the bound only holds when $n$ (which is in our case, $r$) grows large. The $\approx -0.434r$ bound only holds asymptotically, and not necessarily for small $r$.

But I think in page 4 of the paper, they do give bounds of $\frac{1}{r}+\frac{2\sin(r\theta)}{r\theta}\pm2\theta$, which appear to holds for my counterexample, so looking at that might lead to something interesting.
